# $\mathbb{C^2}$ treated as a real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, orthogonality, orthonormal

As a real vector space the dimension is 4. What is an orthonormal basis for it with respect to either the standard real inner product?. I've tried gram schmidt with the obvious choice of 4 vectors( 0,1),(1,0),(i,0),(0,i)
But I keep getting a new set which isn't even orthogonal.can someone help.
If I'm treating it as a real vector surely I am right to use the definition of real inner product and bilinear form as opposed to complex and sesquilinear form just because there's complex numbers involved?

Comment: The bilinear pairing is not positive-definite: $\langle(1, i), (1, i)\rangle = 1^{2} + i^{2} = 0$, for example. Your "surely I am right" claim is difficult to interpret without details of your calculations, but it's entirely possible that verbatim use of the bilinear pairing in Gram-Schmidt leads to trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Those four vectors are already orthonormal.  Note that the real inner product should be defined as the real part of the complex inner product.  So for instance, $\langle (1,0),(i,0)\rangle=\operatorname{Re}(1\cdot (-i)+0\cdot 0)=0$.

Comment: Why should it be defined that way?

Comment: If you want the real inner product to give the same norm as the complex inner product, this definition is forced on you by polarization: $4\langle x,y\rangle_\mathbb{R}=\langle x+y,x+y\rangle_\mathbb{R}-\langle x-y,x-y\rangle_\mathbb{R}=\langle x+y,x+y\rangle_\mathbb{C}-\langle x-y,x-y\rangle_\mathbb{C}=4\operatorname{Re}(\langle x,y\rangle_\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: In any case, in the question you said you wanted to use "the standard real inner product", and this is the standard definition.